# Formatting the columns in the dataframe before saving it to excel

Tags: python, excel, xmlhttprequest

''' def excel_data(request, data):
# Create an Excel writer object with custom formatting
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(BytesIO(), engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

```
# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
workbook = excel_writer.book
worksheet = excel_writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add custom formatting (for example, formatting the 'Percentage' column as a percentage)
percentage_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
worksheet.set_column('AZ:AZ', None, percentage_format)

# Save the Excel file to a BytesIO object
excel_writer.save()
excel_data = excel_writer.buffer.getvalue()
excel_writer.close()

# Create the HttpResponse with the Excel file
response = HttpResponse(excel_data, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
file = "YieldImprovement_Datenexport_" + dt.date.today().strftime("%d%m%Y") + ".xlsx"
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file

return response
```

'''
After using this code , I am getting Module Not found error .

Can anyone please help me what is the reason?

Comment: Please post the error message you are seeing. More details regarding what module is not being found. The error traceback will contain the information we need to help.

Comment: This is the error:                                                                             
ModuleNotFoundError at /index/
No module named 'xlsxwriter'

Comment: And you have (pip install XlsxWriter) and (import xlsxwriter) in your script, right?

Comment: I did that already, still error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Are you install all modules do you need ?

```
pip install pandas xlsxwriter
```

And you need to call all your modules

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
import xlsxwriter
```